# External consultant hired to help on small project in big corp, but colleague there might not want me to be "too good" of a help

Tags: software-development, consulting

*(TLDR; at the bottom)*

Alright, even to write the post title was quite of a challenge cause this is such a bizarre situation I never ever encountered that it's quite hard to explain with few words.

I work as a senior software developer for a small consulting company and recently got assigned to work on a big corporation (let's call it BigComp). The project is actually very easy : just migrate a "codebase" (you will see why the quotes soon) that are written in Python 2.X to Python 3.x .

== DAY 1 ==

Right on my 1st day, I go there to meet the team (small team of 4) and get a briefing on the code, what does it do and how to get access to work on it. There's just one guy (let's call him Bob) that is actually responsible for the code and that I'll be directly working with. Mind you, he's not a software developer but a data scientist/data analyst who learned a bit of coding for the specific purposes he needed on analysing his data.

Already a disappointing surprise in that day is that I'm actually forced to use BigComp's laptop since it's their policy (or so says Bob). It's in a different OS that I'm comfortable working with and now I see there's time to be spent setting all my environment up there with IDEs and whatever development tools I already have on my own working laptop. For such a short project it's really an unnecessary waste of time but mainly how that will decrease my productivity. I can't even type the special characters properly on that keyboard, without having to google how to. But I'm trying to be flexible and although I voiced to them this issue and how I feel, I say "no problem, I'll try my best".

Then more roadblocks appear: it's one of these computers inside the company's network where everything is blocked/locked you need access and permissions here and there to do anything. I ask if I can have admin permissions. Bob is always playing devil's advocate for BigCompany saying probably not, it's not company policy yada yada, but I should ask the manager since he is the one that gives approval. So I send an email to the manager (let's call him Zach) and explain that as a software dev, big part of my work is to actually use and experiment external tools, change configurations and OS environment variables etc, so I need to have some sort of freedom to move on my own computer.

As for the code itself and working with Bob. He is stuck in the past. He does not have an actual software or codebase organized as project. It's just a bunch of files here and there in folders ran by bash scripts. There's no package manager, no pip, no virtual environment (which in Python it's always recommended to have). He does not even use an IDE, he uses IDLE which is like a Notepad. Forget code completion or debugging tools. This guy is coding like people used to do in the 90s. So i mention that before jumping into migration we need to take care of that and install some proper environment, tooling etc. Bob is already showing concerns. He says we can't install any software on the machine as we want. We need to use the tools available by BigComp Software Central, an intranet website where employees download software they need, which of course there's nothing there really relevant for a dev. Another roadblock: Bob does not want this code to go to github or in a cloud repository, everything needs to be in the local machine cause "it's sensitive data". This makes no sense at this day and age and clearly is some sort of paranoia or fear from people who are absolute clueless about tech (or so I think). Also I point it out that the code there's really nothing sensitive about it. It's actually a really bad code that just does file manipulations and put graphs on a pdf. The actual sensitive data is the input of those scripts which I actually don't need in order to do my work

Bob also shows concern regarding on how am I going to code. He mentions he just doesn't understand lambda functions, classes, decorators and a few other things and ask me to avoid using it in my code to which I reply "Absolutely not." And I explain to him that I should not avoid a feature the language provides me just because someone else doesn't understand it, but I guarantee him that if I do I'll make sure to go through that specific piece of code and help him with it.

I go home and tell my manager in my company how it went and that it does not look good, that basically I can't work the way they want me to work and this is going to be a problem.

== DAY 2 ==

I get a reply from Zach saying it's okay to have the admin rights on the computer, but the software installation likely has to go through the approval channels. Well, that doesn't help much. So I have another call with my manager to reinforce at this point I'm not even keen on taking this assignment. He suggests a meeting right away that day with Zach and Bob in it to discuss and me and him present.

In the meeting, only Bob is there, Zach was busy and couldn't join but he told my manager that whatever is the issue "we'll fix it".  So meeting goes surprisingly smooth. I basically repeated myself to Bob about how important is that they provide me the tools I need to get the job done, and my manager reinforced that. Bob was like " yeah, that's fine, however Zach is the guy better to talk about this since I have no authority on the matter"

Great then! We can just talk to Zach and see if he can solve for us! And Zach seemed very easy going regarding these things my manager told me from their phone convo. So we are hopeful this will be sorted.

That day later  I still have another meeting with Bob where we were supposed to catch up on the project and next steps.

And then, in this meeting it's clear as a day to me what's happening. Because in this meeting Bob is being difficult again and he is trying to question "oh but can't you just use this laptop? Can't we skip using a repository? We are so concerned about our data leaving our network etc etc" The same conversation again. He didn't bring any of this during the earlier meeting when my manager was there. All he had to say was "I have no authority". But now he's with me only, although he has no authority he is trying to portray himself as a decision maker in this and throwing absurd suggestions like "Maybe instead of you actually doing the work, you could actually instruct me on how to do it, and I do it, just that I'll do it my way (meaning, his messy folder organization with no package managment, project structure, etc) .

Here is what my gut feeling is telling me about this whole thing: the actual problem is not BigCompany's policies , but rather Bob. I think Bob is that sort of employee who got comfortable on his ways and never really upgraded himself. Sure, he does not have to be a proper software developer or have skills in how to engineer a software, but surely a data analyst today should know some coding ? And if he did dive into coding and chose Python for that, a Python developer for sure should know how to use pip, virtual environments, classes, etc ? The whole reason why they need a consultant to begin with to migrate their code to Python 3. I mean...Python 3 was released in 2008. He's late for the party by 15 years. Bob might be seeing me as a threat, someone who will put his job in jeopardy even maybe.He might be feeling that I'll improve his pipeline in such a way that for him later will be hard to catch up, although I many times said, anything new or he doesn't know I'll go through it together with him. But of course even with my help is inevitable he'll have to put in some effort and learn something. But welcome to programming world. If I had stuck with what I learned from my Computer Science degree days only, today I'd have not survived in this area.

And I'm not sure what his manager is expecting from him when it comes to owning this pipeline but the fact that only with me in private he brings up these "oh don't do it like this, don't use this tool etc" makes me think that he knows he needs to improve.

I think he actually tried to look into some of this things I already brought up that needs to be in place, but he did not succeed in learning them (probably due also to lack of time since this is not his main focus on his role) and now he is afraid he has no option but to actually learn it. The ideal goal in Bob's head is that I make his project work on a new python version without actually changing the way it's structured or the way he works. Thats just not possible.

So, what I need help here is that I don't really know how to approach this situation. When it comes to Bob, I will definitely stand my ground here and not concede to his requests of not using modern techniques and I'll abide to delivery quality work as his company as paying my company for, but because of that it might come to a point of non-agreement between us and then I guess my manager and his will step in. When that happens that's how I don't know to approach. How to make his manager see that the problem here is that Bob is not willing to step up his game and it's creating this paranoia of things that can go wrong to justify that without actually saying that out flat, because of course I'm not interested in stirring drama in their team. It's their problem and they need to solve it

**TLDR; Consultant on a fresh start feels that colleague at allocated company is trying to make his work difficult to preserve his own self interest because he will have to improve his skills. How to deal with that situation?**

Comment: Are you implying that version control/source code management is only possible by storing it on remote sites such as GitHub? Because that's clearly false: you can run a company repository on an internal server (and I think most companies do); you can even run git purely on your own machine, offline, and still get much of the benefit. Given that, wanting to keep the company's code within the company hardly seems like ‘paranoia’…

Comment: No I'm not implying that. I'm well aware of what you said. I forgot to give context that i asked about such internal repository server which I'm 99% sure this company must have it somehow, but Bob says "there's no such thing" which I believe comes from their specific team clueless even about other possible policies and setups within their own company. Anyway, doesn't matter...I actually quit the assignment and the job altogether lol. Things escalated fast and I just couldn't be bothered anymore

Comment: _"that I make his project work on a new python version without actually changing the way it's structured or the way he works. Thats just not possible."_ Why wouldn't it be possible to just lift and shift the code to Python 3? I think that should be perfectly possible, but you just don't want to do it that way (Bob doesn't seem to be the only headstrong/set in their way person in this). If that is what the client asks for, maybe you should just do that (or cancel the contract).

Comment: tell me then how would you do it, without being able to setup a virtual environment where you can actually compare and switch between the 2 different python versions smoothly , without any IDE and debug tool to help you navigate through the code without having to open multiple files in a Notepad editor like ? Without a package manager to organize all the packages and dependencies conflicts that will happen once all packages get updated? I'm looking forward to your solution

Comment: forced to use a Mac, huh? Yup, annoying. Anyhow, data scientists are *not* software developers and make all of those "if only you'd googled/asked on stack overflow/ followed best or even standard or even *some* kind of practice" mistakes.
Ever seen code by anyone not in the CS department in Uni? Well, good luck.

Comment: @bytepusher: lol, hires an expensive software developer consultant to expect a work to be done not within software development standards. Not annoying, just plain dumb. But doesn't matter. I dropped the job on the next morning and later on that afternoon got a new better one that pays more. Sometimes you just have to turn around from dirty alleys to find the road you were looking after

Comment: Who is going to maintain the code after you're done converting it? If it's not you, it seems like you're ignoring a boatload of requirements so you can work in your comfort zone.

Comment: If Bob will remain the primary developer, turning the code into something he doesn't understand is not helpful at all. Besides, people have been coding without lambdas, classes and decorators for decades. For now, just make it run in Python 3, and if you want, write a memo with recommendations.

Answer (score 7):

You made a few mistakes. Some basic ones are below because they're the first things you should have done.

First off you should have analysed the situation and determined everything you will need. It's a mistake to ask for Admin rights, and then the next day ask for something else etc,. This should be done in one go.

There is no point talking to people without authority unless they're on your side. In your situation I would have rescheduled the meeting until Zach was available.

Work out everything you need to do your tasks, get it approved by someone who has the authority to make it happen and then do your work. Don't let the client dictate the parameters of your work beyond reason. It's much easier to use proper tools and allow them temporary access to a network than to fluff around trying to get individual things done before you can even start being productive. I've done it countless times for consultants. Any mediocre network admin would already have it prepared.

Comment: I think the biggest mistake was indeed during interviews and negotiation not discussing working environment, but I believe this is a mistake from our side but just as much as from Bob. 
As for the requests, I was asking the stuff as they would popup since I was setting up the laptop that day. As soon as I see a block my approach was to tackle it right away since the bureaucracy pipeline there could take hours or days.

And yes, I also think in terms of requests and asking approvals I will avoid Bob from now on. But I didnt know there was even a manager until late that first day

Comment: That's another mistake, you're not tied to their pipeline or anything else. Head straight for the people who can accomplish things and don't bother with anything else is how to do it. Things like 'policy, protocols forbid it, can't this, can't that should be meaningless to you. It's up to them to give you what you need to do the job, you're not an employee. So make it clear what you need. I'd have just taken my laptop and left if they didn't want me using it.

Answer (score 6):

There's an old Maxim that I think is applicable here:

"Never ascribe to Malice, that which can be ascribed to stupidity"

Essentially - never assume that there's a evil intent in someone's actions, if they can be explained by human error.

Bob could certainly be setting up roadblocks - but reading through your description of the situation (and something you, yourself, mention) is that Bob sounds like he's stuck in the paradigm of the 2000s:

- Local PC is more secure than the Cloud (debateable)
- No Unapproved software (despite it being industry standard)
- This is how we've always done it etc.

Although I've not met Bob or had the chance to appraise his actions myself, I would say before you jump to the conclusion that Bob is trying to sabotage a project to protect his position (which is a possibility), it's more likely Bob still thinks he is operating within best practices, despite best practices moving on by 20 years.

In terms of how to deal with it - As a contractor/consultant, you have the option of saying 'this isn't worth my time' and walking away. But that is excessive.

I would say that what you need to do in this instance is get a clearly agreed and defined scope of work and the required access/materials to do what is necessary.

Take for example GIT - it's an industry standard tool - you could have in the agreed scope of work that all the new code will be published and maintained to a corporate GIT repository.

If Bob then pipes up about XYZ, you can just point to the agreed document and say 'This is what was agreed' and end the argument.

Comment: Very good point.
As for the GIT, you are right but it's just that for any dev nowadays it's just unthinkable that anyone coding is not using it. I guess we will be defining this scope as we go today (if the whole thing isn't cut short before even starts lol)

Comment: (The maxim you're referring to is [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).)

Answer (score 6):

From how I'm reading your question, your massively over-egging what you're supposed to be doing.  Your job is to convert Python 2 code to Python 3.

But what you seem to want to do is implement a new version control system, add a new IDE and re-architect the whole thing using the latest best practice Python coding style.

Stop trying to be clever.  Tweak the code to compile under Python 3 (there's an automatic tool that should do most of it for you), check that it still works, and it's job done.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Bob is the Big Comp eyes on this matter and he is the client in the sense all this work is for his usage in the Company.
If he can't use the new software then Big Comp has problem.
It would be interesting knowing where come from the request to updated Python version. I would start from there.

Comment: my believe is that the request came from Bob itself. Doing a little digging I saw that one of the libraries he is using just recently announced the completely drop for python 2 version. And he needs that library so he is completely out of option here but to port this to python 3. So in my opinion he'd have let the project stay as it is for as long as possible but now it has become a tick timing bomb, the migration is needed but he can't do it on his own . He is the only one with knowledge, even if limited on what the code does and etc.

Comment: @HugoHowarts: You should find out requirements and stakeholders precisely. This shouldn't be a mystery novel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to repeat the advice of others, which is very good already. I'm just going to suggest you make a proposal to this colleague.

Suggest a trade to him. You can help set him up so that he learns all about Python lambdas, classes, decorators, etc. And in exchange, you ask that he helps you navigate the internal office politics to get the requisite approvals you need to get your job done.